# How to export same metadata multiple times on same class

Tags: c#, .net, mef

Given an exported class with an associated metadata view, is it possible to export the same metadata view multiple times into effectively a single metadata object? Below is an example of why I would want to do this, i.e. the metadata being exported is multiple lists of strings, which logically makes more sense as multiple attributes:

```
[ExportHandledNamespace("System", "Data")]
[ExportHandledNamespace("System", "Core")]    
public class NamespaceHandler : INamespaceHandler { }

public interface INamespaceHandlerMetadata
{
    string[] HandledNamespaces { get; }
}

[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ExportHandledNamespaceAttribute : ExportAttribute, INamespaceHandlerMetadata
{
    // In my use case, NamespaceHandler would be in a plugin assembly 
    // and I don't want them using this delimiter themselves
    private string _namespaceDelimiter = ".";

    public string[] HandledNamespaces { get; }

    public ExportHandledNamespaceAttribute(params string[] namespaceIdentifiers) 
           : base(typeof(INamespaceHandler))
    {
        string namespace = String.Join(_namespaceDelimiter, namespaceIdentifiers);
        // Somehow add this to an existing metadata view's HandledNamespaces
    }
}
```

This is how I would want to use such an export:

```
public void ExampleUsageMethod() 
{
    var handler = mefContainer.GetExports<INamespaceHandler, INamespaceHandlerMetadata>().First();
    string[] handledNamespaces = handler.Metadata.HandledNamespaces;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by splitting `ExportHandledNamespaceAttribute` into a single `Export` on `INamespaceHandler` and a `MetadataAttribute` on the namespace identifiers with a custom metadata view, as below. The trick here is to get the contracts between the import expected by `INamespaceHandlerMetadata` and the export provided by `HandlesNamespaceAttribute` exactly right. Let me know if I can improve/clarify this answer any:

```
[Export(typeof(INamespaceHandler))]
[HandlesNamespace("System", "Data")]
[HandlesNamespace("System", "Core")]    
public class NamespaceHandler : INamespaceHandler { }

[MetadataViewImplementation(typeof(NamespaceHandlerMetadata))]
public interface INamespaceHandlerMetadata
{
    string[] HandledNamespaces { get; set; }
}

public class NamespaceHandlerMetadata : INamespaceHandlerMetadata 
{
    string[] HandledNamespaces { get; set; }

    public NamespaceHandlerMetadata(IDictionary<string, object> exportedMetadata)
    {
        HandledNamespaces = exportedMetadata[nameof(HandledNamespaces)];
    }
}

[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class HandlesNamespaceAttribute : Attribute
{
    private string _namespaceDelimiter = ".";

    // Because the attribute is marked AllowMultiple = true, this will get exported 
    // as a string[], despite it appearing to only be set once in the constructor below
    public string HandledNamespaces { get; }

    public ExportHandledNamespaceAttribute(params string[] namespaceIdentifiers) 
           : base(typeof(INamespaceHandler))
    {
        string namespace = String.Join(_namespaceDelimiter, namespaceIdentifiers);
        HandledNamespaces = namespace;
    }
}
```

The example usage is the same as in the question, querying for an export of `Lazy<INamespaceHandler, INamespaceHandlerMetadata>` and getting its `HandledNamespaces`. But another example use case is below, using `ImportMany`

```
public class NamespaceHandlerManager, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
    [ImportMany]
    public IEnumerable<Lazy<INamespaceHandler, INamespaceHandlerMetadata>> NamespaceHandlers { get; set; }

    public NamespaceHandlerManager() { }

    public void OnImportsSatisfied()
    {
        // NamespaceHandlers will be populated with the exports from any 
        // loaded assemblies by this point, do what you want with it
    }
}
```